# How do you customize a GET asynchronous api call in React Native?

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, post, async-await, get

I have a GET request that retrieves a list of names. I want to add my own text to the results like "The people's names are..." followed by the list retrieved. I am also trying to make sure each name is on a separate line.

This is my GET request. It works just fine like this.

```
state = {
    results: '',
};

onLoad = async () => {
    this.setState({ results: 'Loading, please wait...' });
    const response = await
    fetch('url', {
        method: 'GET',
    });
    const results = await response.text();
    this.setState({ results });
}
```

I tried using split.('\n') but that does not work. I also tried adding strings to the the call but that does not work either. I tried looking on the [react native website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) but I do not understand how to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the results string with `.split(",")` method and rejoin with `.join("<br>")`
Where the `","` is the delimiter used in your string, and `"<br>"` is the delimiter you want to use for new lines in your output.

You can then prepend the "People's names are:" by joining two strings with `+`.

`let s = "People's names are: " + results`

Comment: does <br> works in react-native?

Comment: @Ragnar I mentioned above to replace the <br> with whatever delimiter is required...